# ZendService\Twitterを使って、ユーザーのメールアドレスを取得したい

Tags: php, twitter

下記 Twitter API ドキュメントに従って、
OAuth 認証時にユーザーのメールアドレスを取得しようと試みています。

[GET account/verify_credentials | Twitter Developers](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials)

上記ドキュメントによると、

> #### Request a User's Email Address
>
> Requesting a user's email address requires your application to be whitelisted by Twitter. 
>   To request access, *please use this form*.
>
> Once whitelisted, 
>   the *“Request email addresses from users” checkbox* will be available under your app permissions on apps.twitter.com. 
>   *Privacy Policy* URL and *Terms of Service* URL fields will also be available 
>   under settings which are required for email access.
>
> If enabled, 
>   users will be informed via the oauth/authorize dialog 
>   that your app can access their email address.

ということなので、
whitelist の申請とアプリケーションの設定を済ませました。

> Twitter Application Management
>   ttps://apps.twitter.com
>   Settings
>   　1. Callback URL
>   　2. Privacy Policy URL
>   　3. Terms of Service URL
>   Permissions
>   　Additional Permissions
>   　These additional permissions require that you provide URLs 
>   　to your application or service's privacy policy and terms of service. 
>   　You can configure these fields in your Application Settings.
>   　[x] Request email addresses from users

[image: 2016-03-02_023924]

---

その後、前述のドキュメント内の「OAuth Signature Generator」を使って "cURL command" を生成。

> cURL command
>   OAuth Tool
>   　$ curl
>   　--get 'ttps://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json'
>   　--data 'include_email=true'
>   　--header 'Authorization: OAuth 
>   　　oauth_consumer_key="...",
>   　　oauth_signature="...",
>   　　oauth_nonce="...",
>   　　oauth_token="...",
>   　　oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
>   　　oauth_timestamp="1456854748",
>   　　oauth_version="1.0"'

返ってくる JSON に email が含まれていることを確認しました。

```
{
  "id":...,
  "name":"...",
  ...
  "email":"..."
}
```

---

一方、下記 ZendService\Twitter component を使って同じように
Twitter ユーザーのメールアドレスを取得しようと試みました。

- [zendframework/ZendService_Twitter - Github](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendService_Twitter)
- [ZendService\Twitter — Zend Framework 2 2.4.8 documentation - Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zendservice.twitter.html)

#### index.php

```php
$config = array(
  'access_token' => array(
    'token'  => '...',
    'secret' => '...'
  ),
  'oauth_options' => array(
    'consumerKey' => '...',
    'consumerSecret' => '...',
  ),
  'http_client_options' => array(
    'adapter' => 'Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl',
    'curloptions' => array(
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    ),
  ),
);

$twitter = new ZendService\Twitter\Twitter($config);

$params = ['include_email' => true];
$response = $twitter->account->verifyCredentials($params);
if (!$response->isSuccess()) {
    die('Something is wrong with my credentials!');
}
```

#### library\ZendService\Twitter\Twitter.php

`include_email=true` が付くように、コードの一部を改変しています。

```php
/**
 * Verify Account Credentials
 *
 * @throws Http\Client\Exception\ExceptionInterface if HTTP request fails or times out
 * @throws Exception\DomainException if unable to decode JSON payload
 * @return Response
 */
public function accountVerifyCredentials($params = array())
{
  $this->init();
  $response = $this->get('account/verify_credentials', $params);
  return new Response($response);
}
```

curl では取得できていた email が、php では取れていません。

email 以外のユーザー情報は取れています。

何が間違っているのでしょう？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trueを文字列に変えて試してみればいかがでしょうか？

```
$params = ['include_email' => 'true'];
```

Comment: 私もそう思って試したのですが、失敗してたと思います。念の為、再度試してみます。アドバイス、ありがとうございます。

Comment: 確認しました。majumawm さん、正解です。

"true" にしてよ～く探したら、email 有りました。

boolean true の場合、内部で true → 1 に変換されてるなぁ、と思いながら 1 も試した覚えあるのですが、encode された結果が twitter 側で include_email が 1 ではなく true でなきゃならないなら、そうなるでしょうね。

majumawm さん、ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

パラメータの引き渡し方は特に問題なさそうですし、実際他の情報は取得できているのですよね。Responseクラスも汎用的なものなのでemailだけパースに失敗しているとも考えにくいです。

となると、各トークンにメールアドレス参照の権限が付与されていないことが考えられます。例えば申請を行っていないトークンで試したところ、include_emailを指定しても特にエラーにはならず、emailを含まないレスポンスが返ってきました。

- ConsumerKey/ConsumerSecretがホワイトリスト申請を行ったものと一致しているかどうか
- AccessToken/AccessSecretが**ホワイトリスト申請の後に発行されたものかどうか**

を確認してみてください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
再度試してみます。